# Dataproc web UI doesn't show any metrics such as "CPU Utilization"

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running MLLIb Spark Jobs on Google Dataproc. These jobs are compute-intensive and take more than 20 minutes to complete.

However, when I go to the "Cluster details" web UI, where it would show the "cpu utilization", in a graphic form, I get nothing but a "No data for this time interval" message, no matter the time interval I choose.

For me, this is a completely inoperative UI. Not only for me, but for other people in my company who are playing with Dataproc.

Any idea on what could be happening? Some time zone issue, maybe?

Comment: What image version are you using? And are you seeing same result on other image versions?

Answer (score 1):

There was a [disruption on Dec 21 for GCS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfy5Y.png) that was related to Cloud Functions and Cloud Build rather than Dataproc, not sure is this affected Dataproc, but it seems that everything is ok today according to a quick [test in my Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBYQF.png), would you mind confirm if issue persists in your end?

Keep in mind that if instances were stopped for long time, most probably that is the cause of the message 'No data for this time interval', I got exactly the same message when I shut down my cluster for 6 hours.

On the other hand, even when CPU Utilization in your Console could be a good option for monitoring your Dataproc cluster, I strongly recommend checking the YARN UI for a deeper usage overview of the cluster.